# Determinants in Jordan algebras of Euclidean type

Tags: reference-request, octonions, non-associative-algebras, jordan-algebras

As far as I heard (I am not sure about the precise statement) there is a classification of simple Jordan algebras of Euclidean type.  Each (some?) of such algebras admits a cone of positive definite elements, and there is a version of determinant in terms of which one can formulate a version of the Sylvester criterion of positive definiteness. E.g. basic examples are real symmetric and complex Hermitian matrices, and all the relevant notions are standard. A less standard example is quaternionic Hermitian matrices, where positivity is defined as in the real and complex cases, but the determinant is not so well known - it is called the Moore determinant.

> I am interested in the exceptional example of such an algebra - Hermitian 3x3 matrices with octonionic entries. I would like to have a reference to the explicit formula for the determinant.

Answer (score 3):

We denote by $J_{3}(\mathbb{O})$ be the space:
$$ J_{3}(\mathbb{O}) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & a_1 & \overline{a_2} \\ \overline{a_1} & \lambda_2 & a_3 \\ a_2 & \overline{a_3} & \lambda_3 \end{pmatrix}, \ a_i \in \mathbb{O}, \ \lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}  \right\}.$$
For any $A \in J_3(\mathbb{O})$, we denote by $\det_{\mathbb{O}}(A)$ the number:

$${\det}_{\mathbb{O}}(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 + a_1(a_3a_2) + \big((\overline{a_2})( \overline{a_3}) \big)(\overline{a_1}) - \lambda_2 a_2 \overline{a_2} - \lambda_1 a_3 \overline{a_3} - \lambda_3 a_1 \overline{a_1}.$$ Hence for any $A \in J_3(\mathbb{O})$, we have:

$${\det}_{\mathbb{O}}(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 + 2\mathfrak{Re}(a_1a_3a_2) - \lambda_2 \|a_2\|^2 - \lambda_1 \|a_3\|^2 - \lambda_3 \|a_1\|^2.$$

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a reference to this formula?

Comment: @orbits : well this is just the "classical" formula for a 3*3 matrix. The remarkable fact is that it is real. I don't know who first made this observation. It's probably very old and I have no idea how to provide an acurate reference.

Answer (score 2):

Makt wrote:

> As far as I heard (I am not sure about the precise statement) there is a classification of simple Jordan algebras of Euclidean type.

Yes, in this paper

- Pascual Jordan, John von Neumann and Eugene Wigner, On an algebraic generalization of the quantum mechanical formalism, *Ann. Math.* **35** (1934), 29–64.

the authors proved:

**Theorem.** Every finite-dimensional Euclidean Jordan
algebra is isomorphic to a direct sum of simple ones, and these are all the simple ones:

- $\mathfrak{h}_n(\mathbb{R})$: $n \times n$ self-adjoint real
  matrices with $a \circ b = \frac{1}{2}(ab + ba)$.
- $\mathfrak{h}_n(\mathbb{C})$: $n \times n$ self-adjoint complex
  matrices with $a \circ b = \frac{1}{2}(ab + ba)$.
- $\mathfrak{h}_n(\mathbb{H})$: $n \times n$ self-adjoint quaternionic  matrices with $a \circ b = \frac{1}{2}(ab + ba)$.
- $\mathfrak{h}_n(\mathbb{O})$: $n \times n$ self-adjoint octonionic matrices with $a \circ b = \frac{1}{2}(ab + ba)$ where $n \le 3$.
- The **spin factors** $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus \mathbb{R}$, with
  $$ (x,t) \circ(x', t') =
  (t x' + t' x, x \cdot x' + tt'). $$

Every Euclidean Jordan algebra comes automatically with a cone of positive definite elements, a determinant function, a trace function, and much more.  A good place to learn about these is here:

- Jacques Faraut and Adam Korányi, *Analysis on Symmetric Cones*, Oxford University Press, Oxford, 1994.

The determinant on $\mathfrak{h}_3(\mathbb{O})$ is given by

$$
\det \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  
                         \alpha  &  z  & y^*         \\  
                         z^*       & \beta & x           \\ 
                         y       & x^* & \gamma   \end{array} \right) = 
\alpha \beta \gamma - (\alpha \|x\|^2 + \beta \|y\|^2 + \gamma \|z\|^2)
+ 2 \mathrm{Re}(xyz) 
$$

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y,z \in \mathbb{O}$.  You can check that

$$ \mathrm{Re}((xy)z) = \mathrm{Re}(x(yz)) $$

for any octonions $x,y,z$, so this justifies us in writing either one as $\mathrm{Re}(xyz)$.

For more, including more references, try

- John Baez, [The octonions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105155), [Section 3.4](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node12.html): $\mathbb{O}\mathrm{P}^2$ and the exceptional Jordan algebra, *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* **39** (2002), 145–205.